# Telegram Bot custom keyboard in C#

Tags: c#, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I tried to create message with custom keyboard. So I send request with

```
reply_markup = {"keyboard":[["1"],["2"]],"resize_keyboard":"True","one_time_keyboard":"True"}
```

But, it does not work.

I tried all of Content-Types:

1. application/x-www-form-urlencoded (create message with default
   keyboard)
2. application/json (create message with default keyboard)
3. multipart/form-data (does not work at all, inspite of [this Post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Telegram/comments/3bblz0/sendmessage_with_replykeyboardmarkup_problem))

I also tried to send message by 2 different ways. What's the wrong with this code?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace DutyReminder
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string message = "message";
        string message1 = "message1";
        string botid = "165749848:AAGtjn42bajF-WxdKosTF07sLwJPYlqiDZE";
        string chatid = "38651047";

        Sender.send("", "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + botid + "/sendmessage?chat_id=" + chatid + "&text=" + message + "&reply_markup={\"keyboard\":[[\"1\"],[\"2\"]],\"resize_keyboard\":\"True\",\"one_time_keyboard\":\"True\"}");
        Sender.HttpPost("https://api.telegram.org/bot" + botid + "/sendmessage?chat_id=" + chatid + "&text=" + message1 + "&reply_markup={\"keyboard\":[[\"1\"],[\"2\"]],\"resize_keyboard\":\"True\",\"one_time_keyboard\":\"True\"}", "");

    }
}

static class Sender
{
    static public void send(string message, string url)
    {
        // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
        request.Method = "POST";
        // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
        //string postData = "{\"value1\":\"" + message + "\"}";
        string postData = message;
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
        //  request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        // Get the request stream.
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        // Write the data to the request stream.
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        // Close the Stream object.
        dataStream.Close();
        // Get the response.
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        // Display the status.
        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        // Read the content.
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        // Display the content.
        Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
        // Clean up the streams.
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
    }


    static public string HttpPost(string URI, string Parameters)
    {
        System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URI);
      //  req.Proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy(ProxyString, true);
        //Add these, as we're doing a POST
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.Method = "POST";
        //We need to count how many bytes we're sending. Post'ed Faked Forms should be name=value&
        byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Parameters);
        req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        System.IO.Stream os = req.GetRequestStream();
        os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); //Push it out there
        os.Close();
        System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
        if (resp == null) return null;
        System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
        return sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: What error do you get? May be you should add try-catch-Blocks to your code to get a detailed error message.

Comment: There are no errors, but there is no custom keyboard also
http://f6.s.qip.ru/echeMYh9.png

Is seems that telegram ignore reply_markup parameter.

Comment: So what response do you get? I think, the first question is, is there a communication problem or a command problem.

Comment: I get response:
{"ok":true,"result":{"message_id":65,"from":{"id":165749848,"first_name":"Duty","username":"DutyBot"},"chat":{"id":38651047,"first_name":"\u0413\u0440\u0438\u0448\u0430","type":"private"},"date":1453290235,"text":"message1"}}


If is will use `request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data"` as recomended [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Telegram/comments/3bblz0/sendmessage_with_replykeyboardmarkup_problem) there will be no message sended and i will recieve nothing.

Comment: I found out the solution fof the problem. 
I should use "resize_keyboard\":\"true\" instead of resize_keyboard\":\"True\".

Answer (score 9):

Use the following instead of URI message sending:

```
var bot = new Api("YourApiToken");
.
.
.

var rmu = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup();

rmu.Keyboard =
    new string[][]
    {
        new string[] {"1-1", "1-2"},
        new string[] {"2"},
        new string[] {"3-1", "3-2" , "3-3" }
    };

await bot.SendTextMessage(update.Message.Chat.Id, msg, false, 0, rmu);
```

**UPDATED**
With the newer version of API:

```
var bot = new Api("YourApiToken");
.
.
.

var rkm = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup();

rkm.Keyboard = 
    new KeyboardButton[][]
    {
        new KeyboardButton[]
        {
            new KeyboardButton("1-1"),
            new KeyboardButton("1-2")
        },

        new KeyboardButton[]
        {
            new KeyboardButton("2")
        },

        new KeyboardButton[]
        {
            new KeyboardButton("3-1"),
            new KeyboardButton("3-2"),
            new KeyboardButton("3-3")
        }
    };

await bot.SendTextMessage(update.Message.Chat.Id, msg, false, false, 0, rkm );
```

Comment: @Grisha, Just in `Nuget` Type `Install-Package Telegram.Bot`

Comment: @SiyavashHamdi : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39884961/create-dynamic-keyboard-telegram-bot-in-c-sharp-mrroundrobin-api

Answer (score 3):

**You can dynamicly create keyboard.**

```
var rkm = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup();
var rows = new List<KeyboardButton[]>();
var cols = new List<KeyboardButton>();
for (var Index = 1; Index < 17; Index++)
{
    cols.Add(new KeyboardButton("" + Index));
    if (Index%4 != 0) continue;
    rows.Add(cols.ToArray());
    cols = new List<KeyboardButton>();
}
rkm.Keyboard = rows.ToArray();


await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(
    message.Chat.Id,
    "Choose",
    replyMarkup: rkm);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did it my way :)

```
public static class KeyboardHelper
{
        public static ReplyKeyboardMarkup GetKeyboard(List<string> keys)
        {
            var rkm = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup();
            var rows = new List<KeyboardButton[]>();
            var cols = new List<KeyboardButton>();
            foreach (var t in keys)
            {
                cols.Add(new KeyboardButton(t));
                rows.Add(cols.ToArray());
                cols = new List<KeyboardButton>();
            }
            rkm.Keyboard = rows.ToArray();
            return rkm;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> items = new List<string>();

items.Add("A");
items.Add("B");
items.Add("C");
items.Add("D");
items.Add("E");                               
                                  

var rkm = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup();
var rows = new List<KeyboardButton[]>();
var cols = new List<KeyboardButton>();   
for (var Index = 1; Index < items.Count+1; Index++)
{
   cols.Add(new KeyboardButton("" + items[Index-1]));
   if (Index % 4 != 0) continue;
   rows.Add(cols.ToArray());
   cols = new List<KeyboardButton>();

}
    
if (cols.Count > 0) {rows.Add(cols.ToArray());}

rkm.Keyboard = rows.ToArray();
await Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat.Id,"Choose",replyMarkup: rkm);
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, if possible you should [edit] your answer to include an explanation of *how* this code block answers the question. This helps to provide context and makes your answer much more useful for future readers.