# create dynamic Keyboard telegram bot in c# , MrRoundRobin API

Tags: c#, keyboard, telegram, telegram-bot

I want to create custom keyboard in `telegram.bot`

For example:
We have an array of string that gets from the database or other recurses
how we can push data from the array to `InlineKeyboardMarkup` in for loop or function

```
//array  of Button
string[] ButtonItem= new string[] { "one", "two", "three", "Four" };

//function or solution to create keyboard like this 
var keyboard = new InlineKeyboardMarkup(new[]
    {
        new[] 
        {
            new InlineKeyboardButton("one"),
            new InlineKeyboardButton("two"),
        },
        new[] 
        {
            new InlineKeyboardButton("three"),
            new InlineKeyboardButton("Four"),
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use a separate function to get an array of InlineKeyboardButton

```
private static InlineKeyboardButton[][] GetInlineKeyboard(string [] stringArray)
{
    var keyboardInline = new InlineKeyboardButton[1][];
    var keyboardButtons = new InlineKeyboardButton[stringArray.Length];
    for (var i = 0; i < stringArray.Length; i++)
    {
        keyboardButtons[i] = new InlineKeyboardButton
        {
            Text = stringArray[i],
            CallbackData = "Some Callback Data",
        };
    }
    keyboardInline[0] = keyboardButtons;
    return keyboardInline;
}
```

And then call the function:

```
var buttonItem = new[] { "one", "two", "three", "Four" };
var keyboardMarkup = new InlineKeyboardMarkup(GetInlineKeyboard(buttonItem));
```

Comment: help me this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41519495/how-to-solve-disturbance-in-my-bot-in-c?noredirect=1#comment70247673_41519495

Answer (score 6):

Create InlineKeyboardMarkup in a method:

```
public static InlineKeyboardMarkup InlineKeyboardMarkupMaker(Dictionary<int, string> items)
{
     InlineKeyboardButton[][] ik = items.Select(item => new[]
     {
           new InlineKeyboardButton(item.Key, item.Value)
     }).ToArray();
     return new InlineKeyboardMarkup(ik);
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
var items=new Dictionary<int,string>()
{
     {0 , "True" }
     {1 , "False" }
};
var inlineKeyboardMarkup = InlineKeyboardMarkupMaker(items);
Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat.Id, messageText, replyMarkup: inlineKeyboardMarkup);
```

Selecting True or False make an update with `Update.CallbackQuery.Data`equal to selected item key (0 or 1).

Comment: hi i dont understand this one .are you using a JSON array ?

Comment: I have updated my solution if you see that again you probably found it.

Comment: help me this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41519495/how-to-solve-disturbance-in-my-bot-in-c?noredirect=1#comment70247673_41519495

Answer (score 2):

Create InlineKeyboardButton with specific columns by below method.

```
                public static IReplyMarkup CreateInlineKeyboardButton(Dictionary<string, string> buttonList, int columns)
    {
        int rows = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)buttonList.Count / (double)columns);
        InlineKeyboardButton[][] buttons = new InlineKeyboardButton[rows][];

        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Length; i++)
        {
            buttons[i] = buttonList
                .Skip(i * columns)
                .Take(columns)
                .Select(direction => new InlineKeyboardCallbackButton(
                    direction.Key, direction.Value
                ) as InlineKeyboardCallbackButton)
                .ToArray();
        }
        return new InlineKeyboardMarkup(buttons);
    }
```

Use method like this:

```
        public static IReplyMarkup CreateInLineMainMenuMarkup()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> buttonsList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        buttonsList.Add("one", "DATA1");
        buttonsList.Add("two", "DATA2");
        buttonsList.Add("three", "DATA3");

        return CreateInlineKeyboardButton(buttonsList, 2);
    }
```

Thanks [pouladpld](https://github.com/pouladpld) to create this function.