# Telegram bot dynamic keyboard in c# every button on one row

Tags: dynamic, keyboard, bots, telegram

Hi i new in stackoverflow...
I want to make a keyboard(replykeyboardmarkup) that read data from the database and every button on every row of the keyboard to show .
I read this link:
[create dynamic Keyboard telegram bot in c# , MrRoundRobin API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39884961/create-dynamic-keyboard-telegram-bot-in-c-sharp-mrroundrobin-api)
But all button show in one row...
What i can do?
Tnx!
[like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JP0Al.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private static InlineKeyboardButton[][] GetInlineKeyboard(string[] stringArray)
    {      
        var keyboardInline = new InlineKeyboardButton[stringArray.Length][];
        var keyboardButtons = new InlineKeyboardButton[stringArray.Length];
        for (var i = 0; i < stringArray.Length; i++)
        {

                keyboardButtons[i] = new InlineKeyboardButton
                {
                    Text = stringArray[i],
                    CallbackData = stringArray[i],
                };
            }
        for (var j = 1; j <= stringArray.Length;j++)
        {
            keyboardInline[j-1] = keyboardButtons.Take(1).ToArray();
            keyboardButtons = keyboardButtons.Skip(1).ToArray();
        }

        return keyboardInline;
    }
```