# How to place a button(inline keyboard) in a column on the telegram-api?

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-bot

I try to create custom keyboard for telegram bot.
Use the solution by **AmatuerDev**: [create dynamic Keyboard telegram bot in c# , MrRoundRobin API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39884961/create-dynamic-keyboard-telegram-bot-in-c-sharp-mrroundrobin-api)
and it looks like this :

[button in row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eWxu.png)

How to place a button in a column?

Thanks You!

P.S. Source code:

```
private static InlineKeyboardButton[][] GetInlineKeyboard(string [] 
stringArray)
{
var keyboardInline = new InlineKeyboardButton[1][];
var keyboardButtons = new InlineKeyboardButton[stringArray.Length];
for (var i = 0; i < stringArray.Length; i++)
{
    keyboardButtons[i] = new InlineKeyboardButton
    {
        Text = stringArray[i],
        CallbackData = "Some Callback Data",
    };
}
keyboardInline[0] = keyboardButtons;
return keyboardInline;
}
```

Comment: you mean how to split this keyboard to 2 rows instead of one?

Comment: Yes. I need more 10 rows.

Answer (score 2):

#### Notes:

1. Change return type for `GetInlineKeyboard` to `InlineKeyboardMarkup` instead of `InlineKeyboardButton[][]`
2. Use explicit types instead of implicit (`var`)
3. Use `List<InlineKeyboardButton>` instead of Array (`InlineKeyboardButton[]`)
4. **Don't** create buttons with same callback data
5. Replace method parameters to take `IDictionary<string, string>` to get text and callback data

---

Every `IEnumerable<InlineKeyboardButton>` Is single row, This means you should pass list of rows.

**You shouldn't** use `var keyboardInline = new InlineKeyboardButton[1][];` because this means only one row with buttons in this row!

There are two ways below:

---

### Code you wants:

I don't suggest this code

```cs
private static InlineKeyboardButton[][] GetInlineKeyboard(string[] stringArray)
{
    var keyboardInline = new InlineKeyboardButton[stringArray.Length][];

    for (var i = 0; i < stringArray.Length; i++)
    {
        keyboardInline[i] = new InlineKeyboardButton[]
        {
            new InlineKeyboardButton
            {
                Text = stringArray[i],
                CallbackData = "Some Callback Data",
            };
        }
    }

    return keyboardInline;
}
```

### Best way:

I suggest this code:

```cs
private static InlineKeyboardMarkup GetInlineKeyboard(IDictionary<string, string> buttonsData)
{
    // Rows Count
    int count = buttonsData.Length;

    // List of rows 
    // Every 'List<InlineKeyboardButton>' is row
    List<List<InlineKeyboardButton>> buttons = new List<List<InlineKeyboardButton>>(count);    

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        // Add new row with one button capacity
        buttons.Add(new List<InlineKeyboardButton>(1)
        {
            // Add button to this row
            new InlineKeyboardButton
            {
                Text = buttonsData.Values.ElementAt(i),
                CallbackData = buttonsData.Keys.ElementAt(i),
            }
        });
    }
    
    return new InlineKeyboardMarkup(buttons);
}
```

Comment: Best way is not working :(                     
Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Telegram.Bot.Types.ReplyMarkups.InlineKeyboardButton[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Telegram.Bot.Types.ReplyMarkups.InlineKeyboardButton'

Comment: I followed the login provided in "Best Way" and managed to show inlineButtons one on top of the other.  Reason for my vote up. Thanks Muaath for the solution

Comment: Your best way answer helped me - Jzk -@Muaath, I have answered with new approach which has a new method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the code has massively changed as I haven't tried the above method(answered by Muaath), but this was the fix for me, inspiration from Muaath answer above:

```
public async Task<InlineKeyboardMarkup> GetInlineKeyboardMarkup(IReadOnlyList<SomeClassObject> someClassObject)
        {

            int count = someClassObject.Count;
            List<List<InlineKeyboardButton>> buttons = new List<List<InlineKeyboardButton>>(someClassObject.Count);

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                // Add new row with one button capacity
                buttons.Add(new List<InlineKeyboardButton>(1)
                {
                      InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData(text: $"{someClassObject[i].Title}", callbackData: $"{someClassObject[i].Id}"),
                });
            }

            return new InlineKeyboardMarkup(buttons);
        }
```

Note the difference is there is now a new method: `InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData()`

As per documentation:
https://telegrambots.github.io/book/2/reply-markup.html

Answer (score -1):

You need to put each button in array.
[Reply markup: keyboard & inline keyboard](https://www.botpress.org/docs/telegram/reply-markup-keyboard-inline-keyboard/)